# java.io.FileNotFoundException while running java app from jar file

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

Hi i am running java app from jar file. like following `java -cp test.jar com.test.TestMain` . in the java app i am reading csv file. which is throwing below exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\harinath.BBI0\Desktop\test.jar!\us_postal_codes.csv (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
        at com.test.TestMain.run(TestMain.java:63)
        at com.test.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:43)

*csv file is located in src/main/resources folder.
```

code causes to exception is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TestMain trainerScraper = new TestMain();
    trainerScraper.run();
}

private void run() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    //Get file from resources folder
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    System.out.println(csvFile);
    URL url = classLoader.getResource("us_postal_codes.csv");
    String fileName = url.getFile();
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        line = scanner.nextLine();          //header
        while ((scanner.hasNextLine())) {
```

thanks.

Comment: could you share more code from TestMain.java please

Comment: Also what are these two lines `at com.test.TestMain.run(TestMain.java:63)
        at com.test.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:43)` in your class?

Comment: put `src/main/resources` in classpath

Comment: code updated @ nullpointer. can u check

Comment: 1. would suggest using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to find the current working directory

Comment: as @Sanjeev says, you have to add resources's directory to your classpath.

Comment: @Sanjeev, how can i add the resources's directory to your classpath. can u please brief it.

Answer (score 3):

> test.jar!\us_postal_codes.csv (The filename, directory name, or volume
>   label syntax is incorrect)

Would suggest using

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") // to get the current directory, if the resource is in the project folder
```

and

```
getResourceAsStream("/us_postal_codes.csv") // if its inside a jar
```

Comment: thanks its working. small change   getResourceAsStream("/us_postal_codes.csv")

Comment: @Harinath : my bad, improved

Comment: @Harinath : if this solves your problem, could you please select it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Based on the stack trace below we can see that the Scanner cannot find the file:

```
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
at com.test.TestMain.run(TestMain.java:63)
```

By the way, where is the file? If it's in the jar, then you can use `TestMain.class.getResourceAsStream()` - `Scanner` has an `InputStream` constructor too:

```
InputStream iStream = TestMain.class.getResourceAsStream("/us_postal_codes.csv"); // this supposes the csv is in the root of the jar file
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(iStream)) {
    //...
}
//...
```

Comment: csv file is in jar file. in the root. but still getting exection.
`java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
        at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:608)`

Comment: HI its working fine, i just put '/' to file name like this. "/us_postal_codes.csv". thanks @tamas rev

Answer (score 1):

You should use getResourceAsStream. This is example:

```
public void test3Columns() throws IOException
{
  InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("3Columns.csv");
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
  {
    CSVLineTokenizer tok = new CSVLineTokenizer(line);
    assertEquals("Should be three columns in each row",3,tok.countTokens());
  }
  br.close();
  isr.close();
  is.close();
}
```

ClassLoader.getResource method is not used to search files in .jar archives.